# Adding text labels depending on the position of the line (canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Good Day Stackoverflowers,

I'm creating a floor plan using canvas. I'm a bit stuck on the part of adding labels beside a line.  It should be horizontally and vertically centered and placed outside of the line.

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

[image]

This floorplan is composed of 4 lines. I wish to create a label for each lines depending on the number of lines.

```
this.floorplan.getWalls().forEach((wall) => {
    this.drawWall(wall);
});

private drawWall(wall: Wall) {
    var startX = wall.startX();
    var startY = wall.startY();
    var endX = wall.endX();
    var endY = wall.endY();

    this.context.beginPath();
    this.context.moveTo(startX, startY);
    this.context.lineTo(endX, endY);
    this.context.lineWidth = width;
    this.context.strokeStyle = color;
    this.context.stroke();

    // add labels here
    var label = wall.getLabel();
}
```

Hope someone could shed a light.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi! You can deduce the centered position from the wall coordinates. Then, I noticed that your labels are outside the walls. So, maybe you could add a property to your `Wall` objects, something like `indoor: 'up'` (in the case of the wall D) to show that the side of the wall facing the indoor area is over the line. So if you want to place your label, you will place it under this line. (you can do that with outdoor as well, depending on what works best for you)

Comment: Yes, Thank you. Got it working. Just added a property label details with position so I don't have to worry about calculating it on the fly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure that you know which side of the line is outside or inside you must unify the line directions so that they always move in a clockwise direction.

Then it is easy to locate which side of the line is outside. If standing at the start of the line and looking along the line the outside is to your left left.

The example shows how to render text to the left of the line for both transformed (along the line) un-transformed text and text along the line (ensuring that it is always up)

The un-transformed text is moved away from the line so that the text center is 90deg left of the line center and moved so that the corners fit as close as possible. I have added a thin line from the line center to the text to show where the text center aligns to the line.

```js
requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
const w = canvas.width;
const h= canvas.height;
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawLabledLine(label, x, y, x1, y1, fontSize = 12) {
    ctx.font = fontSize + "px arial";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"; // Rather than mess around with this
                                 // I use the same alignment and just change the
                                 // position to put the text where it is needed
  
    // normalize line
    var nx = x1 - x;
    var ny = y1 - y;
    const dist = (nx * nx + ny * ny) ** 0.5;
    nx /= dist;
    ny /= dist;
    
    // set the transform
    ctx.setTransform(nx, ny, -ny, nx, x, y);
    
    // The transformed is now aligned to the line. Along the line is X and 
    // 90 deg clockwise is right of the line
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(dist, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(dist - 4, -4);
    ctx.stroke();


    var offset = -fontSize * 0.6;
    var distAlong = dist / 2; /// where to put the line
    
    // Use the normal's of the line to workout how
    // to render the text so it is always readable
    if (nx < 0) {
       ctx.setTransform(-nx, -ny, ny, -nx, x, y);
       offset = -offset;
       distAlong = - distAlong;
    }
    ctx.fillText(label, distAlong, offset);

}


function drawLabledLineTextHor(label, x, y, x1, y1, fontSize = 12) {

    ctx.font = fontSize + "px arial";
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.fillStyle = ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    ctx.textBaseline = "middle"; // Rather than mess around with this
                                 // I use the same alignment and just change the
                                 // position to put the text where it is needed
  
    // normalize line
    var nx = x1 - x;
    var ny = y1 - y;
    const dist = (nx * nx + ny * ny) ** 0.5;
    nx /= dist;
    ny /= dist;
    
    // set the transform
    ctx.setTransform(nx, ny, -ny, nx, x, y);
    
    // The transformed is now aligned to the line. Along the line is X and 
    // 90 deg clockwise is right of the line
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(0, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(dist, 0);
    ctx.lineTo(dist - 4, -4);
    ctx.stroke();


    // need the text width so that the text can be moved away from the line
    const textW = ctx.measureText(label).width;
    
    // Offset a little more than half the font size to stop text from
    // touching (top and (bottom if hanging char eg `jgq`))
    var offset = -fontSize * 0.575 - (textW / 2 * -ny) * (-ny < 0 ? -1 : 1);
    var distAlong = dist / 2; // where along the line to move out from (left)
                              // to place the text
    
    // Show center line 
    ctx.lineWidth = 0.25;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineTo(dist / 2, 5);
    ctx.lineTo(dist / 2, offset + fontSize / 2 );
    ctx.stroke();
    
    
    // set transform origin to center of line
    ctx.setTransform(
        1, 0,  // x Axis
        0, 1,  // y Axis
        x + nx * distAlong, // origin
        y + ny * distAlong,
     );
    
    // The vector -ny,nx is CW (right of the line) so the offset is negative
    // to that direction as we want to move left of the line
    ctx.fillText(label, -ny * offset, nx * offset);

}

const points = [
    {x: -40, y: -40, tx: 0, ty: 0}, // tx,ty is tranformed pos
    {x:  40, y: -40, tx: 0, ty: 0},
    {x:  40, y:  40, tx: 0, ty: 0},
    {x: -40, y:  40, tx: 0, ty: 0},
];
const lines = [
    {txt: "A", p1: points[0], p2: points[1], method: drawLabledLine},
    {txt: "B", p1: points[1], p2: points[2], method: drawLabledLineTextHor},
    {txt: "Line C", p1: points[2], p2: points[3], method: drawLabledLine},
    {txt: "Line D", p1: points[3], p2: points[0], method: drawLabledLineTextHor},
]

function mainLoop(time) {
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // default transform
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,w,h);
    var ang = time / 1000;

    // rotate and move to center of canvas all points
    const xAx = Math.cos(ang);
    const xAy = Math.sin(ang);
    for (const p of points) {
        p.tx = p.x * xAx - p.y * xAy + w / 2;
        p.ty = p.x * xAy + p.y * xAx + h / 2;
    }
 
    // render the lines
    for(const l of lines) {
        l.method(l.txt, l.p1.tx, l.p1.ty, l.p2.tx, l.p2.ty);
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(mainLoop);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Well. What can I say. This is amazing. I don't need to add labels manually. Thanks a lot works well.